# Generics BST null pointer

Tags: java, generics, tree

vvI had a BST which only worked on Integer and everything was fine till I tried to change it to generics.

```
public class Tree<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    Node root = null;      

    private class Node {
        T key;
        Node left, right, parent = null;
        Node(T key) {
            this.key = key;
        }
    }  


    public void insert(T key) {       
        if (root == null)
            root = new Node(key);
        else {
            Node actual = root;
            Node parent = null;
            while(actual != null) {
                parent = actual;               
                actual = (actual.key.compareTo(key) > 0) ? actual.left : actual.right;                 
            }
            if (parent.key.compareTo(key) > 0) {
                parent.left = new Node(key);
                parent.left.parent = parent;
            }
            if (parent.key.compareTo(key) <= 0 ) {
                parent.right = new Node(key);
                parent.right.parent = parent;
            }
        }              
    }              
/**********************     end BSTInsert       *******************************/


    public Node search(T key)  {
        Node actual = root;
        while (actual != null && actual.key != key) {
            actual = (actual.key.compareTo(key) > 0) ? actual.left : actual.right;
        }
        if (actual == null) {
            System.out.println("dont exist");
            return null;
        }
        return actual;            
    }

    public void inOrder(Node node) { 
        if (node != null) {
            inOrder(node.left);
            System.out.print(node.key + ", ");
            inOrder(node.right);
        }
    }
}
```

This is small part of code. Funcion search has problem with null pointer as well as the rest of my function (are not listed) Function search gives null pointer and dont know why. It seems that function insert and inOrder works fine

I suspect that problem lies my understanding of generics in java because code before change worked fine on integers.

Thanks in advance.

@edit
 You're right. The BST tree is fine. The problem lies in this code:

```
   public class TreeTest {
      public static void main(String args[]){
        Tree<String> tree = new Tree<String>();
        tree.insert("a");
        tree.insert("b");
        tree.insert("c");   
        tree.inOrder(tree.root);    
        tree.search("b");                      //everything is fine


        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        String txt;

        txt = read.nextLine();    //write b
        tree.search(txt);      //there is no b in tree
      }
    }
```

Comment: Stacktrace please?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is way easier to understand using recursion.

Second, I can't see your error if you don't show me any.

I've made myself a find in a BST algorithm that is working perfectly:

```
protected Node<E> find(E element, Node<E> node) {
        if (node == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (node.getElement() == element) {
            return node;
        }
        if (node.getElement().compareTo(element) > 0) {
            return find(element, node.getLeft());
        } else {
            return find(element, node.getRight());
        }
    }
```

If you give me more information maybe I can be more of service.